# Song didn't play when the url isn't empy

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phaser-framework

I'm really confused and got stuck building a music game using Phaser js framework.

I need the path audio which saved in localhost. To get that path I'm using AJAX. Here's my AJAX code in phaser :

```
function preload()
{
    game.load.audio('song', pathsong);
}

function getSong()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                pathsong = xmlhttp.responseText;
                alert("succes");
                alert(pathsong);
            }
            else
            {
                alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
                alert(xmlhttp.status);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getsong.php" , true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send();     
}
```

And here's my getsong.php

```
<?php

$path = "asset/audio/music/1.mp3";
echo ($path);
?>
```

The `xmlhttp.readyState` and `xmlhttp.status` return 4 and 200 in a while and give success alert. But the song still didn't play, here's the screenshot of it.

[The stop text is an alert that the song didn't play.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1wNF.png)

I can't understand why it didn't play even that var `pathsong` is not null.
I'm newbie at phaser and still learning about programming.
Please don't blame me, and sorry if my english is bad. I'm really trying hard to explain. ^^v

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should run the **preload()** method right after redefining the **pathsong** variable when AJAX response has been successfully received.

Try to add `preload();` after the line `pathsong = xmlhttp.responseText;`